# 3A754 Gunn diode I-V profile

Tags: rf, diodes, microwave, specifications

Does anyone know what the I-V profile of the (I think Russian-made) 3A754L 140mW Gunn diode looks like? I am new to this device and don't see anything online. I am familiar with the typical IV curve but am looking for this device in particular. A link or reference would be great.

[image]

The image indicates a tolerance of about 140mW. If I test it with a ~500 ohm resistor the current is a linear function of voltage up to 10 V. If I use a 100 ohm resistor the current tapers off at 3.5 V and appear to flatten out 4V. However, I don't see a *drop* in current with increasing voltage, which is what I would expect.

My question specifically is, at what voltage/current range would one expect to see the classic Gunn diode profile? If we simply note a tapering off of I with  V is that good enough? Will the diode likely oscillate somewhere beyond that point?

Thanks for any enlightenment.